# Web8.5- Can content-tags.tld be used instead of cd_tags.tld?

Tags: web8.5, broker

I'll upgrade Tridoin 2013 to Web8.5. Also I'll use RESTful Broker API.
Tridion templates generate Java Tag library, for instance `<ComponentLink>`  when publishing.
On Tridoin 2013, such Tag Library's definition is described in `cd_tags.tld`.
When using SDL Web8.5 RESTful Broker API, `cd_tags.tld` cannot be used because the class name has been modified.

I found `content-tags.tld` in the following folder of installation media.

```
Content Delivery\resources\taglib\META-INF
```

Can `content-tags.tld` be used instead of `cd_tags.tld` on RESTful Broker API?

Regards

Comment: Hi Hirokazu, if you found the answer I gave below correct, can you please mark it as correct? That would make it clearer for other users.

Answer (score 3):

For the REST api you have to use the taglib content-tags.tld. You need to include the files in Content Delivery\roles\api\rest\java\lib in your web application's WEB-INF/lib folder. The classes that implement these tags are in content-tags-*.jar.

For the in-process api, you must use cd_tags.tld. Copy the libs from Content Delivery\roles\api\in-process\java\lib. The classes that implement the tags can be found in cd_dynamic-*.jar.

I can see why this question went unanswered for months. If SDL has documented this, I for one couldn't find it.